# help to translate the Chinese script from this box

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

[image]it's a tea box set that I need help to translate it to English

Comment: 傳承國粹 極致品味 means "Inherit nice or special quality of culture or knowledge of the country. The best skill of taste." 傳承 means inherit. 國粹 means nice or special quality of culture or knowledge of a country. 極致 means the best skill. 品味 means taste.

Comment: It's important to show an attempt at solving these.  This site is more focused on learning (about) the Chinese language, and not keen on off-the-cuff "what's this say?", "what's that say?" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit the ultimate taste of the country